# Magic squares of singly even order,make numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I found a source code which print a magic square of singly even order, how can I return it like a numpy array?

[Source](https://rosettacode.org/mw/index.php?title=Magic_squares_of_singly_even_order&action=edit&section=15)

When i work with doubly even order, i use [that](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Magic_squares_of_doubly_even_order#Python) code, and in the end of code i did it like:

```
        B = numpy.zeros([n, n])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            B[i][j] = arr[i][j]
    return str(B)
```

But for single even order i can't do that becouse I don't know how work line `stdout.write(format_sqr("{0}".format(q[0][i][j]), k))` in function "display"

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO, maybe try the tour and be sure to read How to Ask, To improve your question, you may add a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can simply use `np.array()` to cast the magic square into a numpy array. `np_magic_square = np.array(build_sems(6)[0])`

Comment: @DatHydroGuy thank you!